# Graph API v2.3 , Cannot pass a read permission (read_custom_friendlists) to a request for publish authorization

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to add additional permission to access friends list in my Android App , there are many resources about old API graph but could not find anything for new API , so I tried to add new permission to array but it didn't work and I got above error.

```
public void getProfileInformation()
{
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "publish_actions", "user_birthday", "user_hometown","read_custom_friendlists"}));

    final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            try {
                Log.d("Firstname", object.getString("id"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Response Friend List", response.toString());

        }
    });
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id, email, picture, birthday");
    parameters.putString("user", "100006601683765");

    GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequest = new GraphRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"/{user-id}/", null , HttpMethod.GET ,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    parameters.putString("fields", "id, email, picture, birthday");
                    parameters.putString("user", "100006601683765");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    //request.getParameters();
                    request.executeAsync();

                    Log.d("Yasser List",request.getGraphPath());
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this answer by any chance? there is some confusion around what is required to get the userfriends out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Comment: yes I did , but the problem is it is not only about getting friend list it gives me same error for adding any new permission.

Comment: has the facebook app been set to sandbox mode, and/or the app is in production mode with the approval request from facebook being succesful. This kind of permission requires facebook approval.

Comment: yes , I have done all these procedures.

Comment: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email"));  



instead of this

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "publish_actions", "user_birthday", "user_hometown","read_custom_friendlists"}))

Comment: after that where you need other permission then you you take where it need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Graph API v2.3 , Cannot pass a read permission
>   (read_custom_friendlists) to a request for publish authorization

This error means that you cannot pass these permission in

> logInWithPublishPermissions

you have use

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(instance, Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email"));
```

> NOT This

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "publish_actions", "user_birthday", "user_hometown","read_custom_friendlists"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission 'read_custom_friendlists' seems to be deprecated. See the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/?translation) for more information.